# Does loss_weight=N and diff*N do the same thing in pycaffe?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I tried these two methods with pycaffe:

1. `loss_weigth=100` in prototxt;
2. `net.blobs['fc'].diff[...] = A_loss + 100*B_loss`.

I thought they do the same thing in BP theory, model loss shows the opposite results however.

I want to know what is the difference between those two methods? How should I deal with  loss weights if there are multiple losses?

Comment: if you have multiple losses you simply assign each one its loss_weight in prototxt

Comment: @Shai, Thanks for ur answer, and I truly want to know that what is the difference between those two methods?